# Remove time from dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format but removing part of string?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a date and time in cell C4, in the following format: 01/01/2022 12:30:00
My main goal is to remove the time and just have the following: 01/01/2022

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var daily_data = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Daily Data");

var dateandtime = daily_data.getRange("C4").getValue().toString();
var date = dateandtime.substring(0,10);
daily_data.getRange("C4").setValue(date);
```

However this just outputs the following: Fri Dec 31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, first one question: why do you need the cell having date and time and why do you need to extract just the time? Having a date column and a time column it's not a possibility?

That said... You can use .getDisplayValue() to get what exactly you see in your spreadsheet.

var dateandtime = daily_data.getRange("C4")..getDisplayValue().toString();

The code would be:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var daily_data = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Daily Data");

var dateandtime = daily_data.getRange("C4").getDisplayValue().toString();
var date = dateandtime.substring(0,10);
daily_data.getRange("C4").setValue(date);
```

Comment: Hi, I need just the date because I need to compare the date to another date in another cell. If the time is still attached it seems to round when the dates are compared, which can give an undesired output.  When these cells are compared it compares based on what's in the formula bar (not the display value), so modifying the display value does not help I believe.

Comment: Ok, then the said function will work. That function like I said get exactly what you are seeing in your spreadsheet, in other words: "01/01/2022 12:30:00".
With that you can work on the string and get the desired value

Answer (score 3):

From your script, I thought that the value of "C4" might be the date object. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var daily_data = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Daily Data");

daily_data.getRange("C4").setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

or, if you want to set the time to `00:00:00`, please test the following script.

```js
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var daily_data = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Daily Data");

var dateObj = daily_data.getRange("C4").getValue();
dateObj.setHours(0);
dateObj.setMinutes(0);
dateObj.setSeconds(0);
daily_data.getRange("C4").setValue(dateObj).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

- In this modification, the number format of the cell is changed to `dd/MM/yyyy`.
- From your question, I thought that your expected format might be `dd/MM/yyyy`. If you want `MM/dd/yyyy`, please modify it.

#### Reference:

- [setNumberFormat(numberFormat)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)

Comment: Hi, to add some context based on another comment; I need just the date because I need to compare the date to another date in another cell. If the time is still attached it seems to round when the dates are compared, which can give an undesired output.  When these cells are compared it compares based on what's in the formula bar (not the display value), so modifying the display value does not help I believe. Thank you for your help again Tanaike, I will test your solution tonight.

Comment: @Nagaram92 Thank you for replying. From ` I need just the date because I need to compare the date to another date in another cell.`, I understood that in this case, the cell value is required to be the date object. If you want to retrieve the value like "09/06/2022", I thought that my 2nd modification can be used. Because in my 2nd modification, the time is set as `0`. By this, the date can be compared. But, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your actual situation. So if this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Taniake. Thanks again for your help. Your second modification seems ideal but it does not work for me. Somehow the time does not change to 00:00:00 and I am not sure why... it just keeps the original time somehow.

Comment: I've noticed it does change the time, but for some reason the output time is 13:30:01. Any idea why this could be? I have double checked the sheet setting to make sure my location and time settings are correct and they are both correct.

Comment: Okay, with the above, if I set the time to dateObj.setHours(-13);
dateObj.setMinutes(-30);
dateObj.setSeconds(-01); Then it outputs 00:00:00. Not sure why this is but this will do. Thanks again @Taniake. I have marked as solved.

Comment: @Nagaram92 Thank you for replying and testing it again. About `13:30:01`, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand it, for example, when the offset time is reduced from the calculated `dateObj`, can you test it? In this case, please test the script by putting `dateObj = new Date(dateObj.getTime() + (dateObj.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000));` just after the line of `dateObj.setSeconds(0);`. But, if I misundetstood `13:30:01`, I apologize.

Comment: @Nagaram92 By the way, about `I have double checked the sheet setting to make sure my location and time settings are correct and they are both correct.`, in your situation, both timeZones of the Spreadsheet and the Google Apps Script project are the same. Is my understanding correct? I'm worried that if both timeZones are different, the time difference might occur.